# How to type function with generic and default argument in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
function foo<T extends 'hello' | 'goodbye' = 'hello'>(bar: T = 'hello'): void { }
```

`hello` seems to not be valid here, not sure why because it's a part of the `extends` clause. Can someone explain this and potentially provide a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the thing:

```js
function foo<T extends 'hello' | 'goodbye'>(bar: T = 'hello'): void { }
```

can be initiated with

```js
foo<'goodbye'>()
```

But as per your definition of `foo`, the default value would be  `'hello'` which contradicts the statement `foo<'goodbye'>()` which only allows parameter to be `'goodbye'`.

So, with that explanation, you can have the following as your solution:

```js
function foo(bar: 'hello' | 'goodbye' = 'hello'): void { }
```

This works, but I don't think it serves any greater purpose

```js
function foo<T extends 'hello' | 'goodbye'>(bar: T): void { }
```

TS Playground: https://tsplay.dev/WyOzgN