# How to pass a default to a generic function in typescript, where the type of the default argument depends on the genric parameter?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function that calls an API, and accept a parameter to limit the fields the API returns:

```
type MaximumApiResponse = {
    fieldA: string,
    fieldB: number
}

const f = async <U extends keyof MaximumApiResponse>(
    entity: number,
    props: Array<U>
): Promise<null | Pick<MaximumApiResponse, U>> => {
    return await api(entity, props);
}
```

I copied this from the lodash source code and it seems to work fine. It properly deduces what fields the output should have and throws a type error if you try to access a field you have not fetched.

Now, however, I want to set some "default" props. I tried this:

```
const f = async <U extends keyof MaximumApiResponse>(
    entity: number,
    props: Array<U> = ["fieldA"]
): Promise<null | Pick<MaximumApiResponse, U>> => {
    return await api(entity, props);
}
```

If no second argument is given, it will fetch just `fieldA`. The return type should be `{fieldA: string}`. However, this fails:

```
Type '"fieldA"' is not assignable to type 'U'.
  '"fieldA"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'U', but 'U' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'keyof MaximumApiResponse'.
```

I tried this:

```
const f = async <U extends keyof MaximumApiResponse = "fieldA">(
    entity: number,
    props: Array<U> = ["fieldA"]
): Promise<null | Pick<MaximumApiResponse, U>> => {
    return await api(entity, props);
}
```

But it still gives the same error.

Is there any way to allow both the version with a single argument and the two argument version to type check properly?

[I read this but the issue can be solved much easier in that situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70178827/how-to-type-function-with-generic-and-default-argument-in-typescript)

Note I don't care about the function being generic at all, just want a way to limit the output properties but also have a default.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is explained by the TS compiler, and I think the place where you are getting tripped up is TS's use of the `extends` keyword, which in the case of `keyof` narrows the type. The answer that you have linked to is the same question that you have.

As you have written it, I could call `f<'anotherKeyOfMaxApiResponse'>(123)`, which is contradictory, as `["fieldA"]`, the default, is not an array of `'anotherKeyOfMaxApiResponse'`, which I have defined as `U`.

Does the following work, even if it is a little clunky?

```
const f = async <U extends keyof MaximumApiResponse = "fieldA">(
    entity: number,
    props: Array<U> | Array<Extract<keyof MaximumApiResponse, "fieldA">> = ["fieldA"]
): Promise<null | Pick<MaximumApiResponse, U>> => {
    return await api(entity, props);
}
```

I think possibly you might be better off using an overloaded function, but this might work for now.

Comment: Yes I know but how do I fix it?

Comment: An overload might be the best way, I'll accept this answer if you include how to do that (unless an even better answer comes along)

Comment: Do you have a playground set up with `MaximumApiResponse` and `api`?

Comment: This is my starting point at the moment: [Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/m0V3nw)

Comment: @mousetail I had a think, and maybe something like what I've added works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an intersection `&`.

Like `Pick<...> & { ... }`

```
type MaximumApiResponse = {
    fieldA: string,
    fieldB: number
}

const f = async <U extends keyof MaximumApiResponse>(
    entity: number,
    props: Array<U>
): Promise<null | Pick<MaximumApiResponse, U> & { fieldA: string }> => {
    return await api(entity, props);
}
```

You will always have a `fieldA` in your return type

Comment: `&` is an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), not a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  Please [edit] to fix that (or I can do it if you want)